# Bash script to rename file based on parent directory

Tags: bash

Here is a snippet which is aiming to finds files, and rename them based on the name of their parent directory.

I'm trying to get this script to work recursively, but the directory where it is initiated from gets used rather than the location of the results (even with execdir being used).

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec -execdir mv {} ${PWD##*/}.txt \;
```

Is there a way to modify the `${PWD##*/}` bit to acknowledge the execdir command and act from within the file locations directory?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try, note, this will not work if you have spaces, backslash in the folder or filenames.

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=($(echo "$(find . -type d)"))

for dir in ${arr[@]}; do
    files=($dir/*);
    dirname=$(basename $dir);
    echo $dirname; # For testing
    for f in ${files[@]}; do
        if [ -f $f ]; then
            fbase=$(basename $f)
            fbase="$dirname""_""$fbase"
            echo "mv $f $dir/$fbase;" # For testing 
            mv $f $dir/$fbase; # For real.
        fi  
    done
done
```

This is the output of the stdout:

```
B
mv ./B/file1 ./B/B_file1;
mv ./B/file2 ./B/B_file2;
mv ./B/file3 ./B/B_file3;
mv ./B/file4 ./B/B_file4;
mv ./B/file5 ./B/B_file5;
mv ./B/file6 ./B/B_file6;
A
mv ./A/file1 ./A/A_file1;
mv ./A/file2 ./A/A_file2;
mv ./A/file3 ./A/A_file3;
mv ./A/file4 ./A/A_file4;
mv ./A/file5 ./A/A_file5;
mv ./A/file6 ./A/A_file6;
C
mv ./A/C/file1 ./A/C/C_file1;
mv ./A/C/file2 ./A/C/C_file2;
mv ./A/C/file3 ./A/C/C_file3;
mv ./A/C/file4 ./A/C/C_file4;
mv ./A/C/file5 ./A/C/C_file5;
mv ./A/C/file6 ./A/C/C_file6;
```

I don't know if this solves your problem but I imagine this is the general direction.